# Laravel belongsTo relationship not returning values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Im trying to run a hasMany but i really dont know why i dont get any result!
two tables : Company , Joborder, every joborder has a company name and address that i want to get using belongsTo relationship in laravel

```
<?php
namespace App;

class Company extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'company';
    protected $primaryKey = 'company_id';

    public function jobs() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Joborder');
    }
}
```

My Joborder Page

```
<?php
namespace App;

class Joborder extends Model
{
    protected $table      = "joborder";
    public    $primaryKey = "joborder_id";
    protected $dates      = [
        'start_date',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }
}
```

this is PageController:

```
public function joblist() {
    $joblist     = Joborder::all();
    $newInstance = new Joborder;
    $company     = $newInstance->company();

    dd($company->name);
    dd($joblist);

    return view('pages.joblist')->with('jobs',$joblist);
}
```

this is a dd from my page after running

```
BelongsTo {#217 ▼
  #foreignKey: "company_id"
  #otherKey: "company_id"
  #relation: "company"
  #query: Builder {#218 ▶}
  #parent: Joborder {#205 ▼
    #table: "joborder"
    +primaryKey: "joborder_id"
    #dates: array:3 [▼
      0 => "start_date"
      1 => "created_at"
      2 => "updated_at"
    ]
    #guarded: array:1 [▼
      0 => "id"
    ]
    #fillable: []
    #connection: null
    #keyType: "int"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  }
  #related: Company {#212 ▼
    #table: "company"
    #primaryKey: "company_id"
    #guarded: array:1 [▼
      0 => "id"
    ]
    #fillable: []
    #connection: null
    #keyType: "int"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    #morphClass: null
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  }
}
```

I have company_id in company as pkey and in joborder as fkey
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should call

```
$company = $newInstance->company()->get();
```

instead of

```
$company = $newInstance->company();
```

in `PageController:jobList`.
Right now you are returing the relation itself by not the related data.

Alternatively you can access `company` as a property which should automatically return the related data instead of the relation itself:

```
$company = $newInstance->company;
```

Comment: 3 hours on that, tnx . but the collection returns empty. i have some jobs with fkey company_id=1 and a company with the id=1,but im getting null or empty collection. btw i just want the names and address. am i using the right relation here ?

Comment: personally I would stick to laravel eloquent naming conventions, then you dont need to provide addition parameters to resolve the relation. but your model does not therefore you most likely need to provide foreign keys, e.g. `return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'joborder_id');` in `Joborder::company`

Comment: My bad, your `Joborder::company` relation should be `return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'company_id', 'company_id');` In order to get only name and adress you can use `pluck`, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify both `foreignKey` and `localKey` in your both relation, because you don't have id as primary key

Company Model

```
public function jobs() {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Joborder','company_id','company_id');
}
```

Joborder Model

```
public function company(){
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'company_id', 'company_id');
}
```

Now fetch it like this

```
public function joblist() {
    $joblist = Joborder::with('company')->all();

    dd($joblist);

    return view('pages.joblist')->with($joblist);
}
```

If you need to fetch selected field of company then you can specify it in eager loading `$query->select('name', 'address');`

```
public function joblist() {
    $joblist = Joborder::with(['company' => function($query){
                         $query->select('name', 'address');
               }])->get();

    return view('pages.joblist')->with($joblist);
}
```

In blade you can access company data like this

```
@foreach($joblist as $job)
   @if($job->company)
      {{$job->company->name}}
      {{$job->company->address}}
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: did put those but still returning empty

Comment: okay this is exactly what i wanted, only how can i access the company data ? and i dont want it to fetch all company data only name and address is that possible ?

Comment: BIG thanks dude, now im getting BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all(), changed it to get but then im getting ErrorException in 25655af7bffbc458b6eeee304b4909253cf2c9dd.php line 58:
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\resources\views\pages\joblist.blade.php)

Comment: Yes, use `get` and also add `@if($job->company)` condition in blade. i have updated answer check it

Comment: really appreciate the followups,now with all the new changes done,all the relations now returns an empty collection , i did a dd on $joblist and checked it!! im confused

Comment: yes it does show the jobs but not the relation to companies are empty!

Comment: do yo have `company_id` field in `joborder` table ?

Comment: yes i see company_id field in each joborder attributes! but in relation i get    "company" => null

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
public function joblist() {
    $joblist = Joborder::with('company')->get();         
    return view('pages.joblist')->with('jobs',$joblist);
}
```

Ensure that there is ids of joblist in company table.
Also check the foreign key names, Else you have to pass `joborder_id` or whatever the foreign key name is like:

```
public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'joborder_id');
}
```

Comment: Okay! this one works, it gives me the values back , but i dont think its the proper way doing it , why are we even using with when we have the relationships setup already, shouldnt the fuction do the work for us ? by the way how can i access my company data and limit it to fetch name and address only ? and is each company data related to its job ?